# Jest getReversedNavigationSections of null

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a handle on scroll like so:

```
handleOnScroll = () => {
    const {form, navigationSections} = this.props;

    const reversedSections = this.getReversedNavigationSections();

    const OFFSET_TOP = form === 'createIdentity' ? 34 : 140;
    const st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 

    if (st > window.lastScrollTop) {
        for (let i = 0; i < navigationSections.length; i += 1) {
            if (document.getElementById(navigationSections[i].id).getBoundingClientRect().top <= OFFSET_TOP) {
                this.setNavigationActiveWithDebounce(navigationSections[i].id);
            }
        }

    } 

    if (st < window.lastScrollTop) {
        for (let y = 0; y < reversedSections.length; y += 1) {
            if (document.getElementById(navigationSections[y].id).getBoundingClientRect().top <= OFFSET_TOP) {
                this.setNavigationActiveWithDebounce(navigationSections[y].id);
            }
        }
    }

    window.lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;

}
```

and a test for it like so:

```
    it('should handle handleOnScroll', () => {
        window.lastScrollTop = 200;
        window.pageYOffset = 50;

        instance.handleOnScroll();

        expect(instance.getReversedNavigationSections).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I would expect this test to pass (at least for 'getReversedNavigationSections') however I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, have you tried debugging this test yet?

The fact that you are getting that error implies that something is wrong here.

```
document.getElementById(navigationSections[i].id)
```

Which means you aren't getting the element at all.

Without being able to see the rest of your implementation, my initial guess would be that you are splicing Virtual DOM manipulation with direct DOM manipulation and something is getting lost in the mix but I can't tell based on the code snippet.